# Running find from a C program to print file name given inode number?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the file name given the inode number. I am using the `execlp` system call to run the `find` command. My code is shown below:

```
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
 {
    char str[8];
    char *ptr;
    ptr=str;
    long x=9306140;
    snprintf(str,8,"%ld", x);
    execlp("find"," ","~"," ","-inum"," ",str,NULL);

 }
```

But I get an error: Invalid argument '9306140' to -inum.
Could someone please help?

Comment: You don’t want the `” “` arguments.  The shell uses blanks to separate arguments in a string, but doesn’t usually pass them to the command.  The `find` command doesn’t complain about the first two because it just treats them as file/directory names.  It somehow interprets the one after `-inum` as the inode number; it then doesn’t have a meaning for the number.  You also need to ensure you allocated enough space to format the number.

Comment: When I remove " " arguments , it compiles but does not print anything even if a file with that inode exists

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "allocating enough space to format the number"

Comment: The shell expands `~` before running the command.  You’ll need to do `char *home = getenv(“HOME”);` and pass `home` in place of `”~”`.

Comment: 'Enough space' — for the given inode number, you're safe, but generalizing the code could run into problems with not enough space.  You're close to having an 8-digit number; you'd need more space were it to increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, you don't want the `" "` (space) arguments in the `execlp()` argument list.  The shell takes a string with spaces separating the arguments, but it treats what's between the spaces as words that are passed to the command; it doesn't ordinarily pass the spaces to the command.  (That's a simple and sufficient explanation for this exercise; there are caveats and weasel-words galore that could be added.)

The shell also expands `~` to match the value in the `$HOME` environment variable (in contrast to `~user` which gets the home directory of `user` from the password file — they're usually, but not necessarily, the same).

You also have little margin for error in the size of string you've allocated for the number.  Frankly, though, you should simply use a string.  All these changes lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *home = getenv("HOME");
    const char inode[] = "9306140";
    execlp("find", "find", home, "-inum", inode, (char *)NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute 'find' command\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Note the repeated `"find"`; the first is the name of the file to be executed after searching along the path; the second is the value to be provided as `argv[0]`.  You could put `"hypochondriac"` as the second occurrence and it is likely that `find` would work the same, at worst reporting its error messages as coming from the program '`hypochondriac`'.

The next step would be to take the inode number from a command line argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s inode\n", argv[0]);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char *home = getenv("HOME");
    const char *inode = argv[1];
    execlp("find", "find", home, "-inum", inode, (char *)NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute 'find' command\n", argv[0]);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The step after that would be to handle multiple inode values; at that point, you use `execvp()` instead of `execlp()`, though (or, if you're desparate and lazy, you loop and `fork()` and `execlp()` once per inode number, but that's slamming your system for no good reason at all).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked now. But I have a doubt. If the first "find" was the path, then shouldn't we write the complete path like "bin/usr"

Comment: No.  You're using `execlp()` which takes a plain file name (no slash) and searches for an executable with that name in some directory listed in `$PATH` — stopping on the first success.  If you used `execl("/usr/bin/find", …);`, then it would execute the file `/usr/bin/find` (and only that file, failing if it is not present).  If you used `execlp("bin/usr/find", …)` as suggested in the comment, then it would only work if you have a subdirectory `bin` in the current directory containing a subdirectory `usr` and the file `find` in that sub-subdirectory (and the file was executable, etc.).

Comment: Awesome clear explanation!! Really helped. Thank you!

Comment: Note that in the `bin/usr/find` example, `execlp()` would not search the directories in `$PATH` at all.  It would effectively use `.`, the current directory, as the only directory to check.  With `execlp("/usr/bin/find", …)` (note `execlp()` this time, unlike `execl("/usr/bin/find", …)` in the previous comment), it would only attempt to execute the absolute pathname; it would never search along `$PATH` at all.